# Can you iterate a DataFrame without copying memory?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

I am launching a Process that fetches a couple of gigs of data from a database into a DataFrame with a date index. From there I create a Manager to store that data and call a function using a Pool to utilize CPU cores. Since I have so much data, I need to use shared memory for the pooled methods to work on.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd
# Launched from __main__
class MyProcess(mp.Process):
    def calculate():
        # Get and preprocess data
        allMyData = <fetch from Mongo>
        aggs = <resample data into multiple aggregations>
        manager = mp.Manager()
        aggregateData = manager.dict()
        for key, value in aggs.items():
            aggregateData[key] = value

        # Setup the pool and methods
        NUM_PROCESSES = 16
        pool = mp.Pool(processes=NUM_PROCESSES)
        procs = []
        for thing in thousandsOfThingsIWantToCalculate:
            # Run the method asynchronously
            proc = pool.apply_async(method, args=(aggregateData))
            procs.append({proc:[]})

            # Wait so all of the pool methods are not loaded created in memory at once, without this there was a different memory problem
            while len(pool._cache) > NUM_PROCESSES:
                sleep(0.01)

        for dict in procs:
            p, res = next(item(dict.items()))
            res = p.get()
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        # Do stuff with results

def method(data):
    ...
    # Loop through all the data by row
    for row in data.itertuples():
        # Can be empty
    ...
```

Eventually I will get this error and the Process that runs the pool quits. This occurs before the "*for thing in ...*" loop completes.

```
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

I have narrowed everything down to this line in *method*, which I believe is creating a copy of the memory in the row variable that is not efficiently released. If I comment out the line, other memory is consumed but released by the pooled method. If I run the line, even with an empty body and nothing done afterwards, memory is consumed completely.

```
for row in data.itertuples():
```

- Is the row actually a copy of the dataframe data, which would account
  for the excess memory consumption? **Update: YES, also anything increasing retain count is copied (i.e. local variables)**
- I have noticed in other places
  that creating local variables shows memory trouble and to access data
  when needed from the shared memory structure directly. How can I iterate over the
  dataframe without creating a local variable? I can't really vectorize
  the itertuples loop, as it is sequential in nature (the next iteration
  relies on results from the previous).

Thank you for your time.

**Update**:
I can currently get around this problem by reducing the number of processes (16 was a stress test) and setting *maxtasksperchild* on the Pool. I had tried that property before and saw CPU slowdowns (when starting up and memory was being copied now that I think about it), so I scrapped it. CPU seems normal now with it.

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=NUM_PROCESSES, maxtasksperchild=1)
```

Similar behavior is also achieved by garbage collecting after the loop completes, but since that behavior is less desirable, I will stick to *maxtasksperchild*.

As the processes loop, I see a decent size memory drain, but then it is reclaimed by the system when the processes complete. Obviously, as my data set grows and my memory doesn't, this solution will eventually be invalid. **So the question remains, is there a way to iterate over a DataFrame without copying memory?**

Comment: Yes, itertuples creates copies of the data. Why are you using a data-frame here?

Comment: I suppose I don't have to, but it seemed easy to fetch from Mongo into a DF, and my data has 6 or so columns per row. Are you suggesting that working with a numpy array instead wouldn't make a copy?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a particularly compelling reason. There are much more memory efficient ways that you could parallelize, especially if you are fetching from mongo. Just dispense with the Manager, and fetch the rows you need in each process. Or switch to `dask` which implements a distributed data-frame.

Comment: I'm fine with having all of the data in memory at once, not looking to fetch each row on the fly in each pool method. I will look into dask, thanks.

Comment: Each process can fetch the data in chunks, it doesn't have to be single rows. Then it becomes a balancing act between memory/runtime. In any event, this approach seems over-engineered to use pandas do do something it wasn't designed to do.

Comment: That could be the case, but it seemed like Pandas was one of the recommended structures for time series data.